# Hard hypergeometric 4F3

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I could really use some help with the following, which Mathematica confirms:

Show that

$$_4F_3(\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac23;\frac43,\frac43,1;1) = \frac{\beta(1/3,1/3)^2}{27}$$

It has proved very hard for me. I am hoping it is not hard for someone out there. More generally I am looking for a closed form expression for
$$_4F_3(\frac1m,\frac1m,\frac2m,\frac2m;\frac{m+1}m,\frac{m+1}m,1;1)$$
but the case $m=3$ would be a great start. I am hoping that there is some known identity for $_4F_3(a,a,b,b;c,c,1;1)$, but I haven't been able to locate one.

Comment: The conjecture on the $_4F_3$ special value has been recently [reposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794044) to MSE, and received an answer there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked and answered on Math.StackExchange

Comment: Wow, solved 9 years later!!